# Django url dispetcher route by id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

this is my
**views.py**

```
class UserAPI(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated,]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

and this is my **url.py**

```
path('V1/api/users/', UserAPI.as_view(), name='user'),
```

when i enter id,mail,username and go to

```
localhost/v1/api/users/1  want to open user's which id is 1.
```

what is best solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from your url settings your should add primary key to the url. Change this

```
path('V1/api/users/', UserAPI.as_view(), name='user')
```

To this

```
path('V1/api/users/<pk>/', UserAPI.as_view(), name='user'),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
path('V1/api/users/<int:user_id>', UserAPI.as_view(), name='user'),


class UserApi(generics.RetrieveAPIView):

    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated,]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get(self, request, user_id, format=None):

        print(user_id) # do whatever you want with the user id
```

Comment: Not working :) .

Comment: Do you have any error messages?

Comment: When i open localhost/v1/api/users/1 or localhost/v1/api/users/1123123 always open user which id is 1

Comment: if you use "self.request.user" it will print the user you are logged in! Are you trying "print(user_id) like i said?

Comment: get_object() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'request' and 'user_id'

Comment: Change to def get_object(self, request, user_id): and try using APIView instead of generics.RetrieveAPIView